# jQuery - Clearing inputs within a change function

Tags: jquery

How do I change my `on.change` `checkbox` function so that when I press clear, it resets the inputs and runs the `else` part of the function?

I tried changing `this.checked` to: `if ($('input').is(':checked')) {` so that when I clicked clear I could toggle the `$(":checkbox").trigger("change");` to simulate an unchecking of the selected checkbox but the function never executed.

If you click around you will quickly see how the function falls apart. It works well when clicking the first two inputs then clearing, but when you click the third it fails.

**BONUS POINTS** if someone can tell me why the CSS transitions work in this snippet and not at site or even this codepen: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/PvKmJW

The intended behavior is for the tag to not grow/shrink in size like it does in the codepen. The snippet is the intended animation!

```js
$("#m_clear").on("click", function() {
  if ($(":checkbox").prop('checked') == true) {
    $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    $(":checkbox").trigger("change");
  }
});
$(":checkbox").on("change", function(e) {
  var label = $(this).next("label");
  var dot = label.find(".dot");
  var tagbox = $(this).closest(".tagbox");
  var cancel = label.find(".cancel--tagbox");
  var color = label.data("rgb");
  var rgb = `rgb(${color})`;
  var contrast = darkness(color) ? "#202124" : "#fdfdfd";

  if (this.checked) {
    dot.toggleClass("off on");
    dot.css("height", "0px");
    dot.css("width", "0px");
    cancel.css("color", contrast);
    cancel.toggleClass("on off");
    cancel.css("width", "12px");

    tagbox.css({
      "background-color": rgb,
      color: contrast,
      "border-color": rgb,
      color: contrast
    });
  } else {
    dot.toggleClass("off on");
    dot.css("height", "12px");
    dot.css("width", "12px");
    cancel.toggleClass("on off");
    cancel.css("width", "0px");

    tagbox.css({
      "background-color": "#fff",
      color: "",
      "border-color": ""
    });
  }
});

function darkness(color) {
  color.replace(/^\D+|\)/g, "").trim();
  //console.log(color);
  var rgb = color.split(",");
  //console.log(rgb);
  var final =
    parseInt(rgb[0], 10) + parseInt(rgb[1], 10) + parseInt(rgb[2], 10);
  //console.log(final);
  if (final < 384) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font: 400 12px/16px Roboto Mono, monospace;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tagboxes {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.tagbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.text--tagbox {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.cancel--tagbox {
  width: 0px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  color: purple;
  transition: width 0.25s ease;
}

.dot {
  margin-right: 6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

dot.off {
  transform: scale(0);
}

dot.on {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.cancel--tagbox.off {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.cancel--tagbox.on {
  transform: scale(1);
}

#i1+label .dot {
  background-color: rgb(49, 231, 182);
}

#i2+label .dot {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<button id="m_clear">Clear All</button>

<div class="tagboxes">

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i0" type="checkbox">
    <label data-rgb="255,64,129" for="i0">
    <mark style="background-color: rgb(255, 64, 129);" class="dot on"></mark>
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Lobster</b>
    <i class="fas fa-times cancel--tagbox off"></i>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i1" type="checkbox">
    <label data-rgb="49,231,182" for="i1">
    <mark class="dot on"></mark>
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Tuna</b>
    <i class="fas fa-times cancel--tagbox off"></i>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i2" type="checkbox">
    <label data-rgb="0,0,255" for="i2">
    <mark class="dot on"></mark>
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Pine</b>
    <i class="fas fa-times cancel--tagbox off"></i>
  </label>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `each` and `this`, I got it to work. Check out the code below.

```
$("#m_clear").on("click", function() {
 $("input:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
    $(this).trigger("change");
 });
  });
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
  var label = $(this).next("label");
  var dot = label.find(".dot");
  var tagbox = $(this).closest(".tagbox");
  var cancel = label.find(".cancel--tagbox");
  var color = label.data("rgb");
  var rgb = `rgb(${color})`;
  var contrast = darkness(color) ? "#202124" : "#fdfdfd";

  if (this.checked) {
    dot.toggleClass("off on");
    dot.css("height", "0px");
    dot.css("width", "0px");
    cancel.css("color", contrast);
    cancel.toggleClass("on off");
    cancel.css("width", "12px");

    tagbox.css({
      "background-color": rgb,
      color: contrast,
      "border-color": rgb,
      color: contrast
    });
  } else {
    dot.toggleClass("off on");
    dot.css("height", "12px");
    dot.css("width", "12px");
    cancel.toggleClass("on off");
    cancel.css("width", "0px");

    tagbox.css({
      "background-color": "#fff",
      color: "",
      "border-color": ""
    });
  }
});

function darkness(color) {
  color.replace(/^\D+|\)/g, "").trim();
  //console.log(color);
  var rgb = color.split(",");
  //console.log(rgb);
  var final =
    parseInt(rgb[0], 10) + parseInt(rgb[1], 10) + parseInt(rgb[2], 10);
  //console.log(final);
  if (final < 384) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element in the matched set.

so means if first one not set as checked, will not trigger change event.

Answer (score 1):

loop using each is the solution. Use `each` with `this` like below.

```js
$("#m_clear").on("click", function() {
  $(':checkbox').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
      $(this).trigger("change");
    }
  });

});
$(":checkbox").on("change", function(e) {
  var label = $(this).next("label");
  var dot = label.find(".dot");
  var tagbox = $(this).closest(".tagbox");
  var cancel = label.find(".cancel--tagbox");
  var color = label.data("rgb");
  var rgb = `rgb(${color})`;
  var contrast = darkness(color) ? "#202124" : "#fdfdfd";

  if (this.checked) {
    dot.toggleClass("off on");
    dot.css("height", "0px");
    dot.css("width", "0px");
    cancel.css("color", contrast);
    cancel.toggleClass("on off");
    cancel.css("width", "12px");

    tagbox.css({
      "background-color": rgb,
      color: contrast,
      "border-color": rgb,
      color: contrast
    });
  } else {
    dot.toggleClass("off on");
    dot.css("height", "12px");
    dot.css("width", "12px");
    cancel.toggleClass("on off");
    cancel.css("width", "0px");

    tagbox.css({
      "background-color": "#fff",
      color: "",
      "border-color": ""
    });
  }
});

function darkness(color) {
  color.replace(/^\D+|\)/g, "").trim();
  //console.log(color);
  var rgb = color.split(",");
  //console.log(rgb);
  var final =
    parseInt(rgb[0], 10) + parseInt(rgb[1], 10) + parseInt(rgb[2], 10);
  //console.log(final);
  if (final < 384) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font: 400 12px/16px Roboto Mono, monospace;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tagboxes {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.tagbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.text--tagbox {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.cancel--tagbox {
  width: 0px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  color: purple;
  transition: width 0.25s ease;
}

.dot {
  margin-right: 6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

dot.off {
  transform: scale(0);
}

dot.on {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.cancel--tagbox.off {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.cancel--tagbox.on {
  transform: scale(1);
}

#i1+label .dot {
  background-color: rgb(49, 231, 182);
}

#i2+label .dot {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<button id="m_clear">Clear All</button>

<div class="tagboxes">

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i0" type="checkbox">
    <label data-rgb="255,64,129" for="i0">
    <mark style="background-color: rgb(255, 64, 129);" class="dot on"></mark>
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Lobster</b>
    <i class="fas fa-times cancel--tagbox off"></i>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i1" type="checkbox">
    <label data-rgb="49,231,182" for="i1">
    <mark class="dot on"></mark>
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Tuna</b>
    <i class="fas fa-times cancel--tagbox off"></i>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i2" type="checkbox">
    <label data-rgb="0,0,255" for="i2">
    <mark class="dot on"></mark>
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Pine</b>
    <i class="fas fa-times cancel--tagbox off"></i>
  </label>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>
```